# IntelliJ Swing UI Designer Goes To Top Of Form When Trying To Move Components

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea

I'm creating a User Input form for my work, and the swing form I have created is quite long to account for all the info.  I'm using IntelliJ IDEA's Swing GUI Designer to make it easier for a novice like myself. The form is large enough that I have to scroll down to access the lower portions of the form.  However, when I attempt to adjust the position or size of a component, it snaps me to the very top of the form, and I can't move downwards to make my adjustment.  Has anyone else had this problem and/or know a solution around it?
Note: The problem only occurs when editing an existing component, the same problem doesn't occur when adding a new component

Attempted fixes:
holding mouse at bottom of page to see if it scrolls down
using scroll wheel while editing component

Current workaround:
I can adjust the horizontal size of the component by adjusting the mouse where the boundary is intended to be, but at the top of the page.  I can't see the adjustment until after the change is made and I scroll down.  This does not help if I intend to move the component to a new location.

Comment: Please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA with the sample form to reproduce attached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question because I stumbled across a fix that worked for me that's super easy to do. Simply collapsing the component tree window fixes the problem. I'm not certain why this fixes it, but when editing any object with the tree on, the object is deselected (probably because it's changing its physical values) and selects the form it had selected by default.  The form defaults to the top of the page, so when editing it would focus on the form rather than the component, causing the issue.  Collapsing the tree prevents focus on the form and thus prevents the screen from shifting.

Comment: I use cut and paste. This way you don't need to drag anything with a mouse.

Comment: This fix did not help me, but while holding the item the mouse wheel or page down button works for me.